# ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable: [object HTMLSpanElement] has no size and location (Session info: chrome=121.0.6167.86)

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to solving this slider validation. I'm crawling this website's product information (https://www.1688.com/). I upload the image first, and then crawl the image search results. When I repeatedly click on a new webpage and then close it, the slider verification is triggered. Then I tried closing the page and re-running the program. The login page will appear.

[image]

The slider on this page can be found, but it is not interactable.
This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

phoneNumberFind = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#fm-login-id')
print('find number btn')
passwordFind = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#fm-login-password')
print('find password btn')
loginBtn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#login-form > div.fm-btn > button')
print('find login btn')

phoneNumberFind.send_keys(phoneNumber)#input phone number
passwordFind.send_keys(password)#input password
loginBtn.click()
print('click loginBtn')
sleep(3)
slider = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="nc_1_n1z"]')
sleep(1)
ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(on_element=slider).perform()#This line will report an error
```

and

```
<div id="nc_1_n1t" class="nc_scale">
  <div id="nc_1__bg" class="nc_bg" style="width: 0px;"></div>
  <span id="nc_1_n1z" class="nc_iconfont btn_slide" aria-label="滑块" tabindex="0" role="button" style="left: 0px;"></span>
  <div id="nc_1__scale_text" class="scale_text slidetounlock"><span class="nc-lang-cnt" data-nc-lang="SLIDE">向右滑动验证</span></div>
</div>
```

ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable: [object HTMLSpanElement] has no size and location
(Session info: chrome=121.0.6167.86)

I want to know why the element is not interactable and how to solve it.